# Restore Windows 7 Upgraded Computer

Tags: windows-7, windows, partitioning, license, reboot

I have a laptop that came with Windows Vista and I purchased an upgrade to Windows 7. I upgraded the computer to Windows 7. Now I am selling my laptop and would like to restore the laptop to Windows 7 original without my files.

I would also need to wipe all partitions as I dual booted Ubuntu on another partition.

How do I preserve my license? What are the steps I need to take?

Thank you superusers for your help!

Comment: Did you happen to make a full disk backup after you upgraded to a clean windows 7?

Comment: Unfortunately not

Answer (score 2):

[Use Produkey](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/product_cd_key_viewer.html) to record your W7 key.

Re-install Vista "clean" then upgrade to W7 again using the key you recorded using produkey.

Depending on what brand of PC you have there should be factory recovery discs to restore Vista.

Comment: Thanks @Moab. So if I use the Windows Vista recovery discs, wont it ask me to add a license?

Comment: Factory recovery discs will have the Vista licence key integrated, you should only need the W7 upgrade key.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Windows 7 disc of the edition you bought (most likely Home Premium) and enter your upgrade key without having to re-install Vista first.

As Moab mentioned, ProduKey will get you your key back if you lost it, although it should be either in your email or on the sticker in the box you bought.

Comment: Should you have lost the disk then see http://superuser.com/questions/78761/where-do-i-download-windows-7-legally-from-microsoft

Comment: Could I use the Windows 7 upgrade disc I used to upgrade it? Or maybe could I borrow a copy from my friend and use my product key? @pier-luc-gendreau

Comment: It's counter intuitive, but you can use your upgrade disc and key for a fresh install.